# Array of strings - without nesting

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I want my record level data of the form to looks like this:

```
{
   names: ['foo name', 'bar name']
}
```

However I am having to nest which gives me:

```
{
   names: [ { name: 'foo name' }, { name: 'bar name' }]
}
```

The nest is caused by this:

```
        <FieldArray name="names">
          {({ fields }) =>
            fields.map((name, index) => (
              <div key={name}>
                <Field
                  name={`${name}.name`}
                  component="input"
                  placeholder="Name"
                />
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </FieldArray>
```

Is there a way to avoid this nesting, and get a FieldArray of just strings?

Comment: That code, at first glance, looks just fine. Maybe make a sandbox?

Comment: Thanks @ErikR. I figured it out! Instead of `<Field name={\`${name}.name\`}` I changed it to just `<Field name={name}`. Thanks for the attention to a user of your lib when you got much more important things!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I just had to use

```
name={name}
```

instead of

```
name={`${name}.name`}
```

Cool!